# Need Modal Segue BackButton

Tags: objective-c, segue, back-button

this is my code to perform a modal segue when a button is clicked:

```
-(IBAction)segueAction:(id)sender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];}
```

The problem is that when i get in the new View there is no BackButton to get back to the previous one. I'd like it to appear.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[Back]` button does not appear when you show views modally, because there is no navigation stack with which you could go back to a previous view.

You need to either add your own `[Close]` button to the view controller that you opened modally, or use a navigation view controller, and push the new view controller on the stack.

Comment: I can't directly connect buttons to actions in the storyboard because i created an array of buttons in the code. But you are saying i can use the action i created even setting the Segue as "push"? And this will let me have a back button right?

Comment: no it doesn't work if i set it as "push" and then call my performSegueWithIdentifier :(

Comment: I think i'll try adding a "cancel" button, maybe calling it "back" nah?:)

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd I assume that you've got a navigation controller, and the button (or whatever else triggers the segue) is part of the view controller that's displayed in a navigation controller, right?

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd If you display your controller modally, your own "back" button is a good choice.